# Determination of Components of a Set

Tags: general-topology

In the context of the connectedness of a topological space, I would like to know how to determine the components of a set. For example, $\mathbb{R} - \lbrace 0 \rbrace = ( -\infty, 0 ) \cup ( 0, \infty ) $ is disconnected in $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology. $\mathbb{R} - \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ has two components: $( -\infty, 0 )$ and, $( 0, \infty )$. But how do we check that? In other words, if a set $X$ is written as the union of some of its subsets $U_1, U_2, \cdots, U_n$, then how do we know that those subsets form the set of components of $X$?

From my elementary knowledge of topology, I come up with two requirements. They are as follows.

1. All the subsets $U_1, U_2, \cdots, U_n$ need to be disjoint so that their set is a partition of $X$.
2. Each subset $U_i$ needs to have the properties of components of a set: connected, closed and if $A$ is connected in $X$, then $A$ is a subset of a component of $X$.

Is there something that I am missing here? Or, is there any other theorem relevant to it worth knowing?

Answer (score 1):

Do you understand exactly what a (connectedness) component of a set is?  It is defined as a "maximal connected subset" of the set.  That is, A is a component of X if and only if (1) A is connected and (2) any subset of X strictly containing A is not connected.